# Confusion with cloud datastore pagination (limit/cursor)

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Hoping someone can confirm my understanding of cloud datastore pagination, as the documentation is not entirely clear on this.

When querying datastore entities with a result limit, I understand that cloud datastore only guarantees that the number of entities returned will not surpass the the specified limit, but may actually return fewer entities then the limit with a cursor to fetch more.

In my case, I have a datastore kind with ~2000 entities and an index on a "type" property in addition to other indexes. When issuing a query, I include a filter on the "type" property and limit the result to 100 entities. Logically, I expect to receive 100 entities for any type that has at least 100 entities. In reality, I actually receive 30 entities and a cursor to fetch more. Further, using the cursor to fetch more sometimes returns even fewer number of entities then the first batch, still below the request limit and below the total count. The number of entities returned for a given query varies by the entity "type".

Again, I believe this is expected behavior, but I find the inconsistency confusing. Can anyone shed some light on what factors are in play when determining how many entities are returned for a given query? With the exception of a few, most entity "types" are small in size (<1KB) so I can't imagine size is a major factor here.

Using Cloud Firestore in datastore mode and datastore python client library.

Comment: 1) Are you sure of the count of results (i.e. that you have up to 100 results in datastore for records meeting that criteria? 2) You should include your code for running the queries

Comment: No, this is not expected behaviour.